# How to load navigation property in controller without having them in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two classes say Author and Book.

I show you simplified code here

```
class Author
{
    int Id
    string Name
    virtual ICollection<Book> Books;
}

class Book
{
    int Id
    int AuthorId
    string Name
    bool Flag
}
```

In one of my views, I want to edit Author but when saving the object, I want to update some of his books and set the Flag to true;

My save method looks like this

```
public ActionResult SaveAuthor(Author data) 
{
    // call Web API to save Author and also update Flag for some of the data.Books.
    // but data.Books is empty at this point.
}
```

In this method, the `data` parameter, includes author information but, it does not include the Books information so data.Books is empty. The reason is I don't have Books information in my View and View does not bind the Books information.

**My question is how I can populate the Books collection inside SaveAuthor method or preferably inside Web API which saves the author.**

One answer is I should include all books (as hidden field) for the author in view so I can get it back in `data` parameter.

Is there any other way achieve this goal without adding Books into View?

I'm using VS 2015 and probably MVC4

Comment: your book model hasn't `AuthorId` property?

Comment: It actually has. I missed it because I simplified the classes. I add it now

Comment: Personally speaking in preventing using `Include` you are absolutely in the right way. You can simply fetch all related book by `AuthorId` and change their `Flag` property and then assign it to `Author.Books` and finally SaveChanges.

Comment: ```var relatedBooks = _context.Books.Where(item => item.Id == Author.Id).ToList();
Author.Books = relatedBooks.ForEach(item => item.Flag = true);

_context.SaveChanges();```

Comment: I already tried that. loaded Books using it's Web API and got error:  "The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects" when saving changes

Comment: Oh, I got it. the error is because I used a different context object. I loaded the Books using the same context (instead of using it's API) and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I'm happy to hear that. good luck